# Lambda Calculus Function Reduction steps

Tags: lambda-calculus

I am studying **Lambda Calculus**. Could someone help with this reduction?

*(λa.((aλb.λc.c)λd.λe.d))(λf.λg.f)*

The actual result is *λb.λc.c*. But i need the steps to solve it

I have done these steps but i got stuck:

```
(λa.((aλb.λc.c)λd.λe.d))(λf.λg.f)
(λa.(aλb.λd.λe.d))(λf.λg.f)
(λf.λg.f)(λb.λd.λe.d)
(λg.λb.λd.λe.d)
```

Am i doing the steps wrong? Is there any rule I don't know?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Show us your own effort!

Comment: @lemontree I've added the steps I've done

Comment: I got lost in parenteses ;) just fixed an error in *assume* part. Now it should be correct. Oh and if my post answers your question, feel free to also upvote it ;)

Comment: @Pater The correction rsm made on the bracketing of your term is wrong, the starting term with the bracketing as you put it is correct. (The reduction series rsm showed is also correct.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**visual evaluation**

It can be challenging to build a visual model of steps using text alone. As the other answer notes, your `()` are used in a strange way. I hope this answer helps -

```
fix parens:
(λa.((a λb.λc.c) λd.λe.d)) (λf.λg.f)

eval:
(λa.a (λb.λc.c) (λd.λe.d)) (λf.λg.f)
                           =========
    __________________________/
   /
(λa.a (λb.λc.c) (λd.λe.d))
    =    \         \
    |     \         \ 
    |      \         \
(λf.λg.f) (λb.λc.c) (λd.λe.d)
          =========    /
    _________/  ______/
   /           /
(λf.λg.f) (λd.λe.d)
       =     \__
       |        \
(λg.(λb.λc.c)) (λd.λe.d)
               =========
   _______________/
  /
(λg.λb.λc.c)
    =======
     /
    /
λb.λc.c
```

---

**higher intuition**

Incidentally `λb.λc.c` is equivalent to [Church's FALSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_Booleans), `λa.λb.b`. Going back to your original program, given Church's booleans -

```
true := λa.λb.a
false := λa.λb.b
```

Take the original expression -

```
(λa.a (λb.λc.c) (λd.λe.d)) (λf.λg.f)
```

Rewrite using `true` and `false` -

```
(λa.a false true) true
```

Evaluates to -

```
true false true
```

Evaluates to -

```
false
```

We've leaned that `(λa.a false true)` gives us the inverse of a boolean. We can name it `not` -

```
true := λa.λb.a
false := λa.λb.b
not := λp.p false true
```

It works like this -

```
not true //=> false
not false //=> true
```